# xarray - resample time series data from daily to hourly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have a year-long data set (netCDF) with time, latitude and longitude as coordinates, and KBDI-AWAP as variable that's sampled every day.

The data is loaded to xarray's Dataset with Python and is printed as below:

```
print(mds_kbdi)
```

Output:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 106, longitude: 193, time: 365)
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -39.2 -39.149525 ... -33.950478 -33.9
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 140.8 140.84792 140.89584 ... 149.95209 150.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-01-01 2017-01-02 ... 2017-12-31
Data variables:
    KBDI-AWAP  (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 106, 193), chunksize=(31, 106, 193)>
Attributes:
    creationTime:        1525760660
    creationTimeString:  Mon May  7 23:24:20 PDT 2018
    Conventions:         COARDS
```

Put it in details (for each latitude and longitude):

```
Date                       KBDI-AWAP 
2017-01-01                 10.5
2017-01-02                 9.2
2017-01-03                 9.8
...                        ...
2017-12-31                 8.2
```

I would like to resample the KBDI-AWAP values into an interval of a hour. So the dimension of the resampled dataset will be (latitude: 106, longitude: 193, time: 8760). Each KBDI-AWAP value for an hour within the same date should have the same value as the date's value in the original dataset.

The resampled data will be (for each latitude and longitude):

```
Date                       KBDI-AWAP 
2017-01-01T00:00:00        10.5
2017-01-01T01:00:00        10.5
2017-01-01T02:00:00        10.5
...
2017-01-02T00:00:00        9.2
2017-01-02T01:00:00        9.2
2017-01-02T02:00:00        9.2
...
2017-01-03T00:00:00        9.8
2017-01-03T01:00:00        9.8
2017-01-03T02:00:00        9.8         
...                        ...
...                        ...
2017-12-31T21:00:00        8.2
2017-12-31T22:00:00        8.2
2017-12-31T23:00:00        8.2
```

Thinking that I should use the `resample` function on Dataset, I tried with `mds_kbdi_hourly = mds_kbdi.resample(time='H')` but this only output a DatasetResample object instead of a new Dataset.

I tried both pad() and ffill() with the DatasetResample object. The resampled data seems to have missed some data with either of them. The generated ['time'] coordindates are

```
['2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000000' 
'2017-01-01T01:00:00.000000000' 
'2017-01-01T02:00:00.000000000' ... 
'2017-12-30T22:00:00.000000000' 
'2017-12-30T23:00:00.000000000' 
'2017-12-31T00:00:00.000000000'].
```

It is missing timestamps from `2017-12-31T01:00:00.000000000` to `2017-12-31T23:00:00.000000000`. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [`pad`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.resample.DatasetResample.pad.html#xarray.core.resample.DatasetResample.pad) or `ffill` method. For example:

```
mds_kbdi.resample(time='1H').pad()
```

The `resample` method always returns a Resample object. The resample object is only useful if you apply one of its methods (e.g. pad).

Xarray's documentation lists the available resample methods here: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/api.html#resample-objects

and provides some examples of how they are used here: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html#resampling-and-grouped-operations

Comment: Thanks @jhamman. I tried both pad() and ffill() with the DatasetResample object. The resampled data seems to have missed some data with either of them. The generated ['time'] coordindates are `['2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000000' '2017-01-01T01:00:00.000000000'
 '2017-01-01T02:00:00.000000000' ... '2017-12-30T22:00:00.000000000'
 '2017-12-30T23:00:00.000000000' '2017-12-31T00:00:00.000000000']`. It is missing timestamps from `2017-12-31T01:00:00.000000000` to `2017-12-31T23:00:00.000000000`. How to fix this problem?

Comment: You will probably want to explicitly `reindex` before filling. Take a look at the `reindex_like` method.

Comment: I did `mds_kbdi_reindexed = mds_kbdi.reindex_like(mds_temp)`, where mds_temp is another dataset with exactly the coordinates that I would like the KBDI data to have after resampling. Howver, `nan` value is given to all all timestamps other than "T00:00:00".

Comment: Right, so you would then need to ffill after reindexing: `mds_kbdi.reindex_like(mds_temp).ffill('time')`.

Comment: Thanks @jhamman. I am wondering what is the difference using the ffill() and pad() methods.

Comment: @alextc - Funny enough, `pad()` and `ffill()` are identical: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/3cc0d2214d699accb5cd904f775b442083b7bfd8/xarray/core/resample.py#L88